# I have code like this How to code print like this?

Tags: php

input name: DEVO AVIDIANTO PRATAMA
output: DAP
if the input three word , appears DAP

input name: AULIA ABRAR
output: AAB
if the input two words,  appears AAB

input name: AULIA
output: AUL
  if the input one word, appears AUL

```
<?php
$nama = $_POST['nama'];
$arr = explode(" ", $nama);
//var_dump($arr);die;
$jum_kata = count($arr);
//echo $jum_kata;die;
$singkatan = "";
if($jum_kata  == 1){
  //print_r($arr);
  foreach($arr as $kata)
  {
  echo substr($kata, 0,3);
  }
}else if($jum_kata == 2) {
  foreach ($arr as $kata) {
    echo  substr($kata,0,2);
  }
}else {

  foreach ($arr as $kata) {
    echo  substr($kata,0,1);
  }

}

?>
```

how to correct this code :

```
else if($jum_kata == 2) {
  foreach ($arr as $kata) {
    echo  substr($kata,0,2);
  }
```

to print AAB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a variant of another approach. Put each next string over the previous with one step shift. And then slice the start of a resulting string

```
function initials($str, $length=3) {
  $string = '';
  foreach(explode(' ', $str) as $k=>$v) {
    $string = substr($string, 0, $k) . $v;
  }  
  return substr($string, 0, $length);
}

echo initials('DEVO AVIDIANTO PRATAMA'). "\n"; // DAP
echo initials('AULIA ABRAR'). "\n";            // AAB
echo initials('AULIA'). "\n";                  // AUL
```

[demo](https://eval.in/1056974)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
elseif ($jum_kata == 2) {
   echo substr($kata[0],0,1);
   echo substr($kata[1],0,2);
}
```

This will just get the first character of the first word, and then two characters from the next word.
You are returning two characters from each word which is why you get `AUAB`.